# Ruby - Error when trying to parse HTML page using JSON.load(), error 795 or 757

Tags: arrays, ruby, json, hash

I'm trying to parse a page using `JSON.load()`, but unfortunately I always get the same error `JSON::ParserError: 795: unexpected token at '{"`...

It actually works when I don't do the loop. If I set a constant for {page}, let's say 1, it does work. In the loop, it fails.

I assume, there is an error because of the two "{" as I get two Hashes, one for page 1 and one for page 2. Am I right?

Here is my code:

```
@dl_page = []
(1..2).each do |page|
  puts "Loading page #{page}..."
  @dl_page << [ `(curl --url "https://angel.co/video?page=#{page}&sort=joined" -H "X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest")` ]
  @result = "#{@dl_page.join}"
end

html = JSON.load(@result)["html"]
```

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: Why not use Ruby's built in `net/http` library or one of the many HTTP request gems (like HTTParty, which will handle JSON responses automatically) instead of making a system call to `curl`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### What went wrong

First, let's look at what's happening in your code. Here's your loop:

```
@dl_page = []
(1..2).each do |page|
  @dl_page << [ `(curl --url "https://angel.co/video?page=#{page}&sort=joined" -H "X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest")` ]
  @result = "#{@dl_page.join}"
end
```

Let's assume that your `curl` command returns a valid JSON object like `{"html":"foo"}` the first time and `{"html":"bar"}` the second. Let's unroll your loop:

```
@dl_page = []

# First iteration

@dl_page << [ '{"html":"foo"}' ]
# => [ [ '{"html":"foo"}' ] ]

@result = @dl_page.join
# => '{"html":"foo"}'
```

Note that because you appended an array (`[ '{"html":"foo"}' ]`) to `@dl_page` with the `<<` operator, `@dl_page` is now an array with a single element, which itself is an array with a single element. That's probably not what you want. What you probably want is to just append the JSON string itself to the array, i.e. `@dl_page << '{"html":"foo"}'`.

Note also that I replaced `"#{@dl_page.join}"` with `@dl_page.join`. `"#{foo}"` is never necessary. `#{...}` is for string interpolation, and you're not interpolating anything here `Array#join` returns a string, so the above is exactly equivalent to `@result = @dl_page.join`.

The [docs for `Array#join`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Array.html#method-i-join) are a little vague, but as it turns out `[ [ '{"html":"foo"}' ] ].join` just returns `'{"html":"foo"}'`.

As you discovered, if you stop at this point and use `JSON.load` it works, because `@result` is a valid JSON object. Let's find out why, after the second iteration, that's no longer the case:

```
# Second iteration

@dl_page << [ '{"html":"bar"}' ]
# => [ [ '{"html":"foo"}' ], [ '{"html":"bar"}' ] ]

@result = @dl_page.join
# => '{"html":"foo"}{"html":"bar"}'
```

Now `@dl_page` is an array with two elements, each of which is itself an array with one element. When you call `@dl_page.join`, the result is two JSON objects mashed up against one another. Obviously that's not valid, so `JSON.load` fails.

### How to fix it

You have a few superficial problems, like appending an array to `@dl_page` instead of just a single element, and doing `@result = ...`inside the loop when really you only need to do it once, after the loop. Those are issues worth fixing.

The real problem here, however, is that you're trying to turn two JSON strings into one JSON string and then parse it, when you should be parsing each JSON string separately:

```
@result = []

(1..2).each do |page|
  json = `curl --url "https://angel.co/video?page=#{page}&sort=joined" -H "X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest"`
  @result << JSON.parse(json)
end
```

Assuming, again, that the `curl` system call returns `{"html":"foo"}` the first time and `{"html":"bar"}` the second, now the value of `@result` will be an array with two elements, each of which is a Ruby hash:

```
p @result
# => [ { "html" => "foo" }, { "html" => "bar" } ]
```

If you just wanted the values of the `"html"` key, you could instead do this:

```
@result = []
(1..2).each do |page|
  json = `(curl --url "https://angel.co/video?page=#{page}&sort=joined" -H "X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest")`
  @result << JSON.parse(json)["html"]
end
```

Now the value of `@result` will be an array with two strings in it:

```
p @result
# => ["foo", "bar"]
```

We can still do better, however. It's usually the case in Ruby that if you create an empty object outside of a loop and then, inside the loop, add things to that object, you should use `Enumerable#map` or `Enumerable#reduce` instead:

```
@result = (1..2).map do |page|
  json = `curl --url "https://angel.co/video?page=#{page}&sort=joined" -H "X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest"`
  JSON.parse(json)["html"]
end

p @result
# => ["foo", "bar"]
```

Comment: I don't know what to say @Jordan, your comment is fantastic and very helpful to me as I am totally new to Ruby programming. Thank you again for helping people like me to become developer (one day)  :)

Comment: Everyone was once a newbie. Glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

In your code `@result` looks like: `"{"html": "<...>"}{"html": "<...>"}"`. It is not valid JSON.

If you need to concatenate html from both requests:

```
@dl_page = (1..2).map do |page|
  puts "Loading page #{page}..."
  `(curl --url "https://angel.co/video?page=#{page}&sort=joined" -H "X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest")`
end

@result = "[#{@dl_page.join(',')}]"

html = JSON.load(@result)
# => [{"html": "<...>"}, {"html": "<...>"}]
```

Comment: Hi @Sergii K, thanks for your message. I understand that part but I can't figure out how to fix that and convert this to a valid JSON. Any idea?

Comment: Thanks @Sergii K, I figured something out using your code :) Thank you !